# Redirección https multitienda prestashop 1.7

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop1.7

tengo una multitienda con prestashop 1.7 . Funciona en general todo correctamente , incluso los dos dominios diferentes . El único problema que tengo es que si no especifico el https en el dominio me lleva a la url por defecto.

Me explico, si por ejemplo pongo prueba2.com como dominio me lleva al dominio principal https://www.dominioprincipal.com, en cambio si pongo https://www.prueba2.com   funciona perfectamente y no realiza ninguna redirección.

Tengo activado el ssl en el prestashop en los dos dominios.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

¿Debería de funciona no? ¿Le fuerzo una redirección en el ht-acces que machaque la de prestashop?. Cualquier sugerencia es bien aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no la entiendo bien pero sobreentiendo que quieres conectarte a un dominio mediante el nombre de otro. En ese caso puedes hacer una conexión mediante CNAME, es decir el dominio original es https://www.dominioprincipal.com y al vincularlo con CNAME a https://www.prueba2.com podras acceder como indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné creando un redirect del dominio sin las www , eso me lo solucionó.